# Fix Autofill Overlapping With Field Labels

Tags: javascript, css, forms, autofill

I have the Canada Post AddressComplete tool built into my form. It is similar to Google Maps Autocomplete, where once you begin typing your address, it will show suggestions on a drop down.

However, once you select an address, text in the Postal Code and City fields overlaps with the labels. But, when I use Google Chrome to autofill the form, the data appears fine in the Postal Code and City fields.

If it helps, I have included the code for Canada Post AddressComplete below, along with the HTML for the two fields.

You can view the form at https://donorbox.org/youthminds, just select any amount and click next, and that will take you to the second page with the fields.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNU2A.png

Other than hiding the field labels completely, I have not been successful in finding a solution. I have tried JS code I found on other questions about the Chrome autofill overlapping field labels, but they did not work.

Canada Post AddressComplete:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ws1.postescanada-canadapost.ca/css/addresscomplete-2.30.min.css?key=wt22-dj39-nm11-ua29" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ws1.postescanada-canadapost.ca/js/addresscomplete-2.30.min.js?key=wt22-dj39-nm11-ua29"></script>
```

Postal Code Field HTML:

```
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col" id="zip_code_container" style="visibility: visible; position: relative;"><div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label is-invalid is-upgraded" data-upgraded=",MaterialTextfield"><input class="mdl-textfield__input" data-id="text" required="" maxlength="10" size="10" type="text" name="donation[zip_code]" id="donation_zip_code" autocomplete="off"><label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="donation_zip_code">Postal Code</label></div></div>
```

City Field HTML:

```
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col"><div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label is-invalid is-upgraded is-dirty" data-upgraded=",MaterialTextfield"><input class="mdl-textfield__input" data-id="text" required="required" type="text" name="donation[city]" id="donation_city"><label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="donation_city">City</label></div></div>
```

Would it be possible to either fix the overlapping problem with Javascript and/or CSS, or could the field labels be changed to help text, appearing below the field?

The form itself does support help text, but can only be added to additional / extra questions, not existing fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*First*

Hid The Form Labels With CSS:

```
label[for="donation_zip_code"] { display: none !important; }
label[for="donation_city"] { display: none !important; }
```

*Second*

Added Placeholder To Both Fields

The onload event makes the placeholder code load after the rest of the form finishes loading, otherwise it will not work and the placeholder won't be added.

If you can't use the field ID or it does not work, use the field name.

Replace **getElementById('Your Field ID').** *with* **getElementsByName('Your Field Name')[0].**

If the HTML already contains a placeholder, then replace the placeholder code with:

**document.getElementsByName('Your Field Name')[0].placeholder='Your Placeholder';**

*OR*

**document.getElementById("Your Field ID").placeholder='Your Placeholder';**

```
function addLoadEvent(func) {  
      var oldonload = window.onload;  
      if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {  
        window.onload = func;  
      } else {  
        window.onload = function() {  
          if (oldonload) {  
            oldonload();  
          }  
          func();  
        }  
      }  
    }  

   addLoadEvent(function() {  
document.getElementById("donation_zip_code").setAttribute("placeholder", "Postal Code");

    });  

function addLoadEvent(func) {  
      var oldonload = window.onload;  
      if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {  
        window.onload = func;  
      } else {  
        window.onload = function() {  
          if (oldonload) {  
            oldonload();  
          }  
          func();  
        }  
      }  
    }  

   addLoadEvent(function() {  
document.getElementById("donation_city").setAttribute("placeholder", "City");
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't modify the dropdown styles, as it is a native browser element that is not a part of DOM.

My suggestion is to disable the autofill functionality in the html code using the autocomplete="off" attribute:

```
<input type="text" id="foo" value="bar" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: Is there any way I could just hide the form labels, and add help text to both of them using Javascript and/or CSS?